# Select in MySQL and Group per day

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have got a table, which holds rows for campaigns.
Every row has fields named timestamp_start and timestamp_end.

Now I want to read out EVERY campaign with the range in daily grouping from timestamp_start TO timestamp_end.

So, when I got a campaign with ID "1", timestamp_start = '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and timestamp_end = '2014-01-10 23:59:59', I want to get a result like:

```
| ID| day        
|  1 | 2014-01-01    
|  1 | 2014-01-02   
|  1 | 2014-01-03  
|  1 | 2014-01-04  
|  1 | 2014-01-05  
|  1 | 2014-01-06  
|  1 | 2014-01-07  
|  1 | 2014-01-08  
|  1 | 2014-01-09  
|  1 | 2014-01-10
```

When there are more campaigns (e.g. 2, 3), they should be grouped like the same way there, too.

I hope, my description is understandable.

I tried lots of solutions, but none worked for me.

Now I have this query...

```
SELECT campaign_id, DATE(timestamp_start) as timestamp_start 
FROM campaign 
GROUP BY campaign_id, DATE(timestamp_start);
```

... it gives me only one row:

campaign_id = 1 - timestamp_start = '2014-01-01'

So my question is: Can I group per day, when the range comes out of only one single row?

Since I'm trying for at least 7 hours now, I'm really despaired.
I tried rollups, lots of subqueries, ...... :(

Comment: Got no Mysql here to test, but have you tried str_to_date(timestamp_start,'%Y-%m-%d') or left(timestamp_start,10)?

Comment: Yes, I did. The Problem is the range from timestamp_start to timestamp_end. No matter what I do, I always get only 1 row with the start date

Comment: are you executing this in another language?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? :$

Comment: Ah, do you mean, if I start this for example from PHP? Yes, I do. It comes from PHP. The Query is at least lots longer, but there are only more "filters" for campaign_ids, which are not needed specially for my problem.

Comment: well, I just tested [here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/CURRENT_DATE) with query `select wht,date(td) from eclipse group by wht,left(td,10) ` and the results are ok. Remove that `as timestamp_start` in your query

Comment: Yeah, that's true. That is what I except, but that does not consider the fact, that I only have got ONE row (per campaign), which holds the startdate AND the enddate :(

Comment: i.e. you want something like `select wht,date(min(td)),date(max(td)) from eclipse group by wht` (again from [here](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/CURRENT_DATE) )

Comment: Adding the GROUP BY campaign_id is why you only get 1 row (given your example and data) for ID=1. And in your examples you haven't even shown how you handled the check for having the end to the campaign. You should create an SQLFiddle so we could have access to some data.

Comment: May I ask why you need to all this in SQL, why not just get all the campaigns and build an array like you want in PHP?